# Поиск строк и столбцов с наибольшим количеством четных чисел

Tags: python, матрицы

С текстового файла вводится матрица. Программа выпишет номера всех строк, которые содержат наибольшее количество четных чисел (индекс идет с 0). После того, как программа выпишет номера строк, она должна выписать номера столбцов с наибольшим количество четных чисел.
Для этой матрицы:

```
 1  1  2  5  6  1
 5  6  8  5  6  7
11 12 10 12 11 11
 8 10  5  6  7  9
 6  5 10 12 15 19
```

ответ должен быть таким:

```
1
2
3
4
2
```

```
matr = []
m = open("C:\prog\matrix.txt")
for line in m:
    matr.append(list(map(int, line.split())))
mm = [[0] * (len(matr[0]) + 1)]
res = []
for row in matr:
    r, t = [0], 0
    for i, x in enumerate(row, 1):
        t += x & 2
        r.append(t + mm[-1][i])
    mm.append(r)
res = []
res1 = []
for row1 in range(len(matr)):
    for columns in range(len(mm)):
        for a in (matr[columns]):
            if a % 2 == 0:
                res.append(row1)
                continue
            if columns == range(len(mm)):
                row1 += 1
            else:
                continue
```

может кто подскажет как исправить этот код?заранее премного благодарен и С Новым годом всех

Comment: 1) лучше уменьшать код для примера до нужного количества, ведь по сути вам нужно с массивом работать, а не с файлом, поэтому в вопросе можно было вместо считывания из файла сразу предоставить заполненный массив `mm` 2) почему во второй строке значение 2, там ведь три четных числа: 6, 8, 6? Тоже самое и к 4-й и к 5-й строкам

Comment: @gil9red  в ответ идет не количество четных чисел, а номер строки и потом номер столбца с наибольшим количеством четных чисел

Comment: Невнимательно прочитал, виноват :)

Comment: @gil9red ничего страшного)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Накидал пример алгоритма:

```
from collections import defaultdict

matrix = [
    [1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 1],
    [5, 6, 8, 5, 6, 7],
    [11, 12, 10, 12, 11, 11],
    [8, 10, 5, 6, 7, 9],
    [6, 5, 10, 12, 15, 19]
]
row_count = len(matrix)
col_count = len(matrix[0])

# Словари, у которых ключом будет количество четных чисел, а значением список индексов, у которых такое количество
# четных чисел
row_counter = defaultdict(list)
col_counter = defaultdict(list)

for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    even_count = len([x for x in row if x % 2 == 0])

    # Тоже самое что:
    # even_count = 0
    #
    # for x in row:
    #     if x % 2 == 0:
    #         even_count += 1

    row_counter[even_count].append(i)

for j in range(col_count):
    even_count = len([i for i in range(row_count) if matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0])

    # Тоже самое что:
    # even_count = 0
    #
    # for i in range(row_count):
    #     if matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0:
    #         even_count += 1

    col_counter[even_count].append(j)

print(row_counter)  # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: [0], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4]})
print(col_counter)  # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: [0, 4], 3: [1, 3], 4: [2], 0: [5]})

for i in row_counter[max(row_counter)]:
    print(i)

for i in col_counter[max(col_counter)]:
    print(i)
```

---

Алгоритм без использования словарей, а с использованием списка счетчиков:

```
row_count = len(matrix)
col_count = len(matrix[0])

row_counter = [0] * row_count
col_counter = [0] * col_count

for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    row_counter[i] = len([x for x in row if x % 2 == 0])

for j in range(col_count):
    col_counter[j] = len([i for i in range(row_count) if matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0])

print(row_counter)  # [2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
print(col_counter)  # [2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0]

max_of_row = max(row_counter)  # 3
max_of_col = max(col_counter)  # 4

for i in range(len(row_counter)):
    if row_counter[i] == max_of_row:
        print(i)

for i in range(len(col_counter)):
    if col_counter[i] == max_of_col:
        print(i)
```

Результат:

```
1
2
3
4
2
```

Comment: а что делает collections.defaultdict и можно ли его чем-нибудь заменить?

Comment: это словарь, у которого по умолчанию используется указанный тип в качестве значения, в данном случае -- `list`, заменить его можно обычным `dict`, но если у того не будет ключа `even_count`, нужно будет его добавлять и само значение: `if even_count not in row_counter: row_counter[even_count] = []`

Comment: понял, спасибо большое, открыл теперь для себя модуль collections

Comment: Подумал, что можно и без словарей сделать, вот и расширил ответ :) Если ответ устроил, отметьте как правильный

Answer (score 0):

```
row_counter = [len([x for x in row if not x % 2]) for row in matrix]
col_counter = [len([i for i in z if not i % 2]) for z in zip(*matrix)]
max_of_row = max(row_counter)
max_of_col = max(col_counter)
print(*(e for e, i in enumerate(row_counter) if i == max_of_row), *(e for e, i in enumerate(col_counter) if i == max_of_col), sep='\n')
```

- 

```
row_counter = {e: len([x for x in row if not x % 2]) for e, row in enumerate(matrix)}
col_counter = {e: len([i for i in z if not i % 2]) for e, z in enumerate(zip(*matrix))}
print(*(k for d, m in ([row_counter, max(row_counter.values())], [col_counter, max(col_counter.values())]) for k in d if d[k] == m), sep='\n')
```